# Show that the sequence is bounded below 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

$a_1=1$  $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$  $a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}$

then $$a_k\lt3$$
$$-a_k\gt-3$$
$$-\frac{1}{a_k}\lt-\frac13$$
$$3-\frac{1}{a_k}\lt3-\frac13$$
$$a_{k+1}\lt\frac83$$

But i shoud have gotten $a_{k+1}\lt3$ to be able to conclude that $a_k\lt3$

What am i doing here wrong?

Do i need to get exactly $a_k\lt3$ in order to prove that this sequnce is bounded below 3? Because $\frac 83$ is still smaller that 3

Comment: you can just prove it by induction.

Comment: isn't this induction i am doing

Comment: @EldarRahim This is just inequality manipulation! Not Induction.

Comment: $3-\frac{1}{a_k}$ is $a_{k+1}$. Isn't this induction? I had to show my steps about how i got there. My book does the same process and says it is induction

Comment: Note the for $n=1$, $a_n=1$, so the statement is already holds. Now assume that the statement also holds for $n=k$, i.e., assume $a_k<3$. Now show that this implies $a_{k+1}<3$

Comment: And also $8/3<3$, so showing that something is less than $8/3$, implies it is also less than $3$.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to get but i get $\frac 83$. Why do i get this? What am i doing wrong is my question

Comment: Am i doing something wrong that i get a fraction or is this the right way of doing it? From the examples on my book, all solutions concluded at the very same expression, not any less not any more.

Comment: you are doing alright.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove else that $a_n>0$.

If so then by your work $$a_{k+1}<\frac{8}{3}<3.$$

Also, $a_1<3$, which says $a_n<3$ for all natural $n$ by induction.

The fact that $a_n>0$ we can prove by induction again.

Indeed, we'll prove that even $a_n>\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}.$

$a_1=1>\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}$ and if $a_n>\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}$ we have
$$a_{n+1}-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}=3-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}-\frac{1}{a_n}=$$
$$=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{2}{3-\sqrt5}-\frac{1}{a_n}>0$$
and we are done by induction.